# What is meaning of this PowerShell Script?

Tags: windows, powershell

I am new in PowerShell Script.
I came across a **statement** but not able to understand the meaning of following statement:

```
Function-Name |  %{ some x statement } | ? { some Y statement }
```

Anyone can guide me for this problem. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: take a look at `Get-Alias '?'`, `Get-Alias %`, and the `Get-Help` for the commands that show up. also, the `|` symbol is called a `pipe` and means "send the output of the item on the left to the item on the right".

Comment: Thanks @Lee_Dailey for quick suggestion. Yes I am going to try it. Thanks Bro for help!

Comment: you are most welcome! glad to have helped somewhat ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After research, below is answer:

> %

is **ForEach-Object**

And

> ?

is **Where-Object**

**Note**: To find such problem OR Cases use **Get-Alias** command.

Example:- **Get-Alias** %

Comment: Maybe share how you found out? :-) Don't forget to accept your own answer!

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Nice Suggestion! I have updated the Answer, how I found out the answer.